# I need to export a 39GB compressed SAS dataset with more than 400 variables and 40mi lines and keep its size. Is it possible?

Tags: sas, export, bigdata

I need to export a 39 GB compressed SAS dataset with more than 400 variables and 40mi lines and keep its size. Is it possible? I tried to export as CSV file but increased to 59 GB. XLSX, XLS, XLSB and TXT also didnt work.

I tried to reduce the lenghts of variables and use compress=no to see if it works, but the CSV file size still much bigger than SAS file. Is there any format that keeps the size or an option that compress the size of CSV file?

i am using the code bellows:

```
 filename _dataout zip "/file_name/dataset_name.zip" member="dataset_name.CSV";
proc export data=dataset_name
  outfile=_dataout
  dbms=CSV replace;
run;
```

Comment: It's impossible to answer whether you can "keep its size" without knowing what the variable metadata is.  Some variables are roughly 1:1 SAS:CSV when compressed, but for example high precision numerics (say, 16.14 format or something like that) are likely much more compressed in SAS than in a compressed CSV.  There are things you can do to then compress that further, such as output the number as a packed binary, but it really depends on your data, and it'll be hard to read back in.

Answer (score 1):

Try increasing the zip compression to max.

```
filename _dataout zip "/file_name/dataset_name.zip" member="dataset_name.CSV" compression=9;
```

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't use zip here. Try using Sqlite if you have the option. Use the SAS/Access to ODBC. I have seen dramatic size reductions using Sqlite.

> libname sqlite odbc complete="dsn=SQLite3 Datasource;Driver={SQLITE3
> ODBC Driver};Database=c:\temp\MyData.sqlite"; data sqlite.cars; set
> sashelp.cars; run;